# Can't find file with os.walk()

Tags: python, file, search, os.walk

I've created a file called program1.py in my /home/n00b directory.
I then opened python and I wanted to see if I could write a script to find it's location. I did this:

```
for f in os.walk('/home/n00b'):
     print 'searching', f
     if 'program1.py' in f:
          print 'found'
          break
```

Why isn't this working? It seems to be searching each file because my screen fills up with the 'searching', part, but it never finds it.

Comment: Sorry if the code looks weird. -Posted from my iPhone explains why. ;O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working because `os.walk` returns a 3-tuple: current directory, list of directory names here, and list of filenames here:

```
for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/n00b'):
     print 'searching', files
     if 'program1.py' in files:
          print 'found'
          break
```

Your print statement should have shown you that.  The `in` operator won't look deeply into the tuple, and since your filename was not one of the three elements in the tuple at any point, your code didn't find it.

Comment: Ahh, so that's why, eh? Muchos gracias.

Answer (score 0):

The function `os.walk()` doesn't work the way you expect. Instead of giving a list of files, it gives a tuple (similar to a list) with Directory, Subdirectory and Files. So, you could use:

```
for d, s, f in os.walk('/home/n00b'):
     print 'searching', d
     if 'program1.py' in f:
          print 'found'
          break
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change f -> f[2] to get the 3rd element of the tuple returned by walk.

```
for f in os.walk('/home/n00b'):
     print 'searching', f
     if 'program1.py' in f[2]:
          print 'found'
          break
```

Comment: Ha! we all got there at the same time ... i prefer Ned's answer because it tells you more about what's going on (and is more useful in general), even though mine only requires a 3 byte change :P